# How to Resolve Maven CDK Plugin Dependency Error when Following Cloudera Demo

Tags: maven, hadoop, cloudera

I'm trying to following along with the Cloudera CDK-examples Demo (https://github.com/cloudera/cdk-examples/tree/master/demo); this is part of a conference (Big Data Techon 2013) session by Cloudera on Hadoop App development

However, I am unable to get `mvn install` to build successfully. I keep getting warnings like this

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no         dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-maven-plugin:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT: Plugin com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-maven-plugin:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT
```

and then it fails with these errors... I tried to troubleshoot on my own using Google and the link mentioned in the error, but it was to no avail

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.263s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 15 15:21:23 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'cdk' in the current project and in the plugin groups         [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/cloudera/.m2/repository), cdh.repo (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos), central     (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `pom.xml` [here](https://github.com/cloudera/cdk-examples/blob/master/demo/pom.xml), I see that the `snapshots` is `disabled` for both `repository` and `pluginRepository`.

You could try to `enable` it and try building.

Comment: Thank you; I will try to test this solution this evening.